# Как исправить ошибку в программе для Arduino?

Tags: java, arduino, serial

Выводит ошибку:

> Функция "showInputDialog()" ожидает параметры:
>   "showInputDialog(Component, Object, String,  int, Icon, Object[],
>   Object)"
>   Функция "showInputDialog()" ожидает параметры:
>   "showInputDialog(Component, Object, String,  int, Icon, Object[],
>   Object)"

```
void selectSerialPort()
{
  String result = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
  "Select the serial port that corresponds to your Arduino board.",
  "Select serial port",
  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
  null,
  Serial.list(),
  0);

 if (result != null) {
  portname = result;
  openSerialPort();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
  null,
  "Select the serial port that corresponds to your Arduino board.",
  "Select serial port",
  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
  null,
  Serial.list(),
  null
);
```